# How to export a submodule in a Typescript library

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

So my goal is to create a library in Typescript. My intention is to split up core parts of the library into submodules like RxJS or Angular Material.

RxJS and Angular both support imports like so:

```
// RxJS
import { map, filter } from 'rxjs/operators';

// Angular
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
```

However, I am unable to replicate this myself.

My goal is to do something similar and allow you to import a class with `import { foo } from 'package/bar`;

I have looked at RxJS's source on Github and have tried replicating what they've done but it's not working.

The library compiles fine but when I go about importing it I always get a `Cannot resolve dependency 'package/foo'` error.
Meanwhile doing `import { test } from package` (without the submodule part) works completely fine.

I've tried using paths in tsconfig to no avail. If that is the answer then I'm doing it wrong.

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: How are you bundling your library? Usually the deep imports are based on it bundled as an es6 module with the directory structure intact, if you bundle it as a umd or iife you can't do this. Are you using webpack?

Comment: if you install your lib locally to node_modules, you should be able to import it like 'package/bar'.

Comment: @David I'm bundling using webpack but the dependency resolving error comes from Typescript's own compiler when I try and compile the project.

Comment: @ABOS Doesn't work. I've used yarn link/npm link and published the package to npm and it still doesn't work. I've tried making 'bar' a sub-directory and put a index.js file there. Doesn't work either. Not sure what to do.

Comment: Ah so it's only internal to the project then? Others don't have to be able to import your library like that?
If so you'll just need the webpack path rewrite plugin. The issue is that while the typescript compiler knows the paths under tsconfig.json, webpack is unaware of them.

Comment: @Noah, I tried locally and it worked, not sure about your setup though

Comment: @DavidSherman It's not internal. The goal is for others to import the library.

Comment: @ABOS I don't think I have anything special in my setup. I'll push something to Github later to check though.

Comment: I think what you want to do is just use the typescript compiler to compile as es modules with the directory structure intact to dist/es and set 'esnext' in package.json to dist/es/index.js
Webpack creates a single output file and that is not what you want for this import style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to achieve that, you can create your "sub-modules" in different directories (although they are technically part of the same module), and create an `index.ts` on each of those directories exporting there whatever you want to publish.

For example, I have done this in my NodeJs package [Flowed](https://github.com/danielduarte/flowed), and you can for example do this:

```
import { FlowManager } from 'flowed/dist/engine';
```

Where the corresponding `index.ts` file is [this one](https://github.com/danielduarte/flowed/blob/master/src/index.ts) if you want to check.

Although in my case I put also available all the stuff from the root, so the previous line would be equivalent to:

```
import { FlowManager } from 'flowed';
```

Comment: Thanks! How can you remove "dist/" from the path?

Comment: To remove the "dist/" part the module developer/s should publish its components in an index file outside the dist directory and you would be able to include it directory.