# How can I use "exports" in package.json for nested submodules and TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm

I want to take advantage of the new-ish ["exports"](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#packages_exports) feature of Node.js/`package.json` so that I can do the following:

```
"exports": {
  ".": "./dist/index.js",
  "./foo": "./dist/path/to/foo.js"
}
```

and users can do the following:

```
import { foo } from 'my-package/foo';
```

TypeScript 4.5 should [support the "exports"](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-5-beta/#packagejson-exports-imports-and-self-referencing) field, yet it does not seem to work. I am building a simple package using TS 4.5.2, and I am consuming that package in a project using TS 4.5.2. I have looked at other [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58990498/new-package-json-exports-field-not-working-with-typescript) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53680866/how-to-export-a-submodule-in-a-typescript-library) and [this GitHub thread](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33079) and [this bug report](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/46339) but can't seem to find a consensus on the issue and whether it should work today.

I am still able to import using the more verbose syntax:

```
import { foo } from 'my-package/dist/path/to/foo.js';
```

I have also tried the object notation for exports, to no avail:

```
"exports": {
  ".": { "require": "./dist/index.js", "import": "./dist/index.js" },
  "./foo": { "require": "./dist/path/to/foo.js", "import": "./dist/path/to/foo.js" }
}
```

Is this feature ready to be used with TypeScript projects today? If yes, what am I missing? Specifics about tsconfig would be useful for both the source project and consuming project. The TS compiler complains about `node12`/`nodenext` being used for either the `module` or `moduleResolution` fields (I am definitely using TS 4.5.2).

Comment: I appreciate you keeping this question updated. They've really helped.

Comment: I think here you mean `moduleResolution`, not `module`?

Comment: @DanielleMadeley Changing module affects moduleResolution: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#module

Comment: @RyanWheale do you by any chance have a pointer to a fully working example? 
I'm still struggling to make this work :(

Comment: @Stvad - I don't - but you should be able to follow any blog post or article about using `exports` and it should work as expected. I recommend starting small and going from there. If you're trying to retrofit an existing project, something else is probably getting in your way. This whole process if fairly simple and straightroward. The most complex part is the tsconfig. See the `tl;dr` section above - that should be all you need, but I'd recommend following a recent blog post for the most up-to-date instructions.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

- Node.js has supported `exports` since v12.7.0 (Jul. 2019)

  When I asked this question (Dec. 2021), NodeJS had supported the `exports` field for  nearly 2.5 years. It seemed reasonable to assume that Typescript supported it.
- The latest version of TypeScript at that time (4.5) did not support the `exports` field.

  This was particularly confusing because the [TS 4.5 beta announcement](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-5-beta/#packagejson-exports-imports-and-self-referencing) said that it would support`package.json` exports.
- Typescript 4.7 (Jun. 2022) finally supported `package.json` exports
- Using `typesVersions` in `package.json` is not the solution

  Several people suggested using `typesVersions` - but that's a completely separate feature which is specific to TypeScript only (read more about it [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/publishing.html#version-selection-with-typesversions)). The `exports` field in `package.json` is a feature of node and should work with any npm module.

So, if you have a Typescript project and you want to be able to import a package which uses package.json "exports", you will need to do the following:

- Your TypeScript project must be using TS v4.7 or later
- Your `tsconfig` should be using `moduleResolution` of `node16` or `nodenext`.

  - You don't have to set `moduleResultion` if you are using `module` with a value of `CommonJS`, `ES2015`, `ES6`, `ES2020`, or `ESNEXT`

Comment: The new `moduleResolution` of `bundler` supports package.json `"imports"` and `"exports"` as well, but unlike the Node.js resolution modes, `bundler` never requires file extensions on relative paths in imports. (https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#moduleResolution)

Comment: I personally don't mind the file extensions and the static analysis it affords - and I highly recommend that you use extensions. This can have a huge performance impact on your app startup time because of the extra file system lookups required to support extension-less imports: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html

Comment: I don't mind your opinion either. I just supplemented your answer with a relatively new option to make a whole picture. In my case it's just default Vite.js setting

Comment: Thanks. Any additional information helps. It is worth noting that you can only use the `bundler` option if you are actually using a bundler like Webpack, Vite, esbuild, Parcel, rollup, swc, etc. If you are just using `tsc` to compile your TS files, you will need to stick with with the `.js` extensions. Here's a good article which covers it: https://dev.to/ayc0/typescript-50-new-mode-bundler-esm-1jic

Comment: "You don't have to set moduleResultion if you are using module with a value of CommonJS, ES2015, ES6, ES2020, or ESNEXT"

if `module` is not set to `nodenext` or `node16`, you MUST set the `moduleResolution`, according to the latest Typescript docs.

"Classic if module is AMD, UMD, System, or ES6/ES2015; Matches if module is node16 or nodenext; Node otherwise."

https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#moduleResolution

Comment: I would also emphasize that the `moduleResolution` needs to be configured correctly, in the project that is importing the module, not the module itself (library, package that's imported by other projects).

Comment: Thanks @0xCourtney - thanks for the clarification. Yes, all of the above information applies to the "consuming" typescript project. JS and Node (without typescript) can handle the exports - this whole question was about "I've got a typescript project and I need to import a package which uses package.json exports". I'll update the answer to clarify.

Answer (score 8):

TypeScript only respects export maps in `package.json` if you use `"moduleResolution": "NodeNext"`(or `"Node16"`) instead of the widespread `"moduleResolution": "Node"`.  (I guess `"moduleResolution"` defaults to the same value as `"module"`, but it's hard to find documentation of this?

Update: in TypeScript 5 there is also a `"moduleResolution": "bundler"` option that also respects export maps.  The differences between the two are:

- `"bundler"` never requires file extensions on relative paths in imports
- `"NodeNext"` will match the `"node"` export condition in export maps, but `"bundler"` won't (not documented yet in the TSConfig reference...haven't managed to find the issue thread where I confirmed this with the TypeScript team)

See: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/esm-node.html
and https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#moduleResolution

A number of TS libraries out there (including many of Microsoft's own) have errors with `"moduleResolution": "NodeNext"` right now because of things like relative imports without explicit file extensions.

Answer (score 5):

Without knowing what error you are getting, or in what other way TypeScript doesn't seem to be working for you (not sure why you would not want to share such crucial information), I can tell that your `exports` section appears to be missing types information. Typically, if your .d.ts files were located next to their respective .js files, your exports section would look like this:

```json
"exports": {
  ".": {
    "types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
    "default": "./dist/index.js"
  },
  "./foo": {
    "types": "./dist/path/to/foo.d.ts",
    "default": "./dist/path/to/foo.js"
  }
}
```

Comment: I think it's clear that I can import using the file path, but not the shortened version per my "exports". There's no error to give you, it just doesn't work. Also, the types are not necessary as TS looks for a `.d.ts` file next to the code files as mentioned in the document I referenced in my question: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-5-beta/#packagejson-exports-imports-and-self-referencing. Regardless, I gave it a try and no dice.

Comment: It doesn't work.
The package.json file doesn't recognize types.

Comment: This solved it in a pure ESM project with NodeJS, ReactJS, babel + Webpack where NodeJS runs on the compiled babel files, but webpack on src.

Instead of `default` i've used `import`, see conditional-exports: https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#conditional-exports

TS 5.1.5; without the `exports` `types` to src, the TS2305 error was thrown

`"exports": { ".": { "import": "./build/index.js", "types": "./src/index.ts" } }`

`paths` in `tsconfig.json` isn't needed, only my IDE uses it it seems

Answer (score 4):

I've been looking to use nested folders for a design system package we created at Pipefy, and after deep research, I found how to do it.

The package exports React components, and we use to import them like this `import { Button } from '@mypackage/design-system;`

Later on, we've added tokens to our design system library, like `Colors`, `Spacing`, and `Fonts`, but we don't want to import everything from the index, it isn't productive.

After some exhaustive research, I found how to export nested folders using TypeScript. My purpose is to use tokens like this `import { Colors } from '@mypackage/design-system/tokens;`

To use your TypeScript lib like this you should use the `typesVersions` inside the `package.json` file.

Here I use it like this

```json
"typesVersions": {
    "*": {
      "index": [
        "lib/components/index.d.ts"
      ],
      "tokens": [
        "lib/tokens/index.d.ts"
      ]
    }
  },
```

It worked like a charm for me, it would work for you too!

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The `typesVersions` has a different purpose (and semantics) than the `exports` field. In particular, `exports` is part of node's module resolution algorithm and works with plain JS. I'm publishing a package that needs to be consumed by both JS and TS projects, and your solution would not work for javascript projects - but it's a neat trick. Hope it helps someone. At the time I wrote this question, there were articles suggesting that TS 4.5 should support `exports`, but it was pulled last minute due to too many use cases and other issues.

Comment: Hey @RyanWheale, looks like the `exports` feature has returned on version 4.7 \o/

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-7/#package-json-exports-imports-and-self-referencing

Comment: Yes! I've been watching closely in anticipation. I'll get the question updated.

Comment: How do we support dule modules in `typesVersions` like `exports`?  
Can we add two the same type definition files for CommonJS and ESM module together?

`
"typesVersions": {
  "*": {
    "utils": [
       "./lib/cjs/utils/index.d.ts",
       "./lib/esm/utils/index.d.ts"
    ]
  }
}
`