# Simple modular imports in a multi-platform NPM package

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, package.json

We're building an NPM package which provides multiple alternative builds for different platforms (e.g. CommonJS, IIFE, native ES): Similar to public examples like `pdfjs-dist` ([package.json here](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/package.json)) and `@aws-sdk/client-s3` ([package.json here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/blob/main/clients/client-s3/package.json)) - with a structure something like:

```
- package.json
- dist/
    - cjs/
        - index.js
        - module1.js
    - es/
        - index.js
        - module1.js
    - iife/
        - index.min.js
    - types/
        - index.d.ts
        - module1.d.ts
```

As far as I can tell, using package.json fields like `main`, `module`, and `types` are sufficient for us to get top-level imports looking nice. For example with `"main": "./dist/index.js"` a TypeScript app can:

```js
import { MyTopLevelClass } from "@example/mypackage";
```

...But for **non-top-level** imports, it seems like users have to understand which build they're using and the internal structure of the package - like:

```js
import { AnotherClass } from "@example/mypackage/dist/cjs/module1";
```

Is there any way (e.g. alternative `package.json` settings or etc) to simplify deep imports on cross-platform projects to go direct to the target build sub-folder? For example:

```js
import { AnotherClass } from "@example/mypackage/module1";
```

---

**Edit** to add:

For a while I hoped [package.json conditional exports](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#conditional-exports) might fix this for a defined set of allowed entry points, by defining something like:

```json
{
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "import": "./dist/es/index.js",
      "require": "./dist/cjs/index.js",
      "types": "./dist/types/index.d.ts"
    },
    "./module1": {
      "import": "./dist/es/module1.js",
      "require": "./dist/cjs/module1.js",
      "types": "./dist/types/module1.d.ts"
    }
  }
}
```

...But it doesn't seem to work for me? Even when setting [nodenext module resolution in tsconfig.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70296652/how-can-i-use-exports-in-package-json-for-nested-submodules-and-typescript). I'm not sure if there's any way to do this without moving (duplicating) type declarations under each of the builds e.g. `cjs`, `es`.